# Does a capsule's color from the Shell-Out Machine mean anything?

Tags: splatoon-3

Capsules from the Shell-Out Machine come in a few different colors. I've seen blue, purple, and red. Does the capsule's color mean anything?

[image: a blue capsule]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are six different rarities (grades) of items available from the Shell-Out Machine, each getting a capsule color.

What players get out of the Shell-Out Machine relies on a component of luck. Each possible item is separated into six grades, with 0 being the rarest and 5 being the most common. Each grade has a different capsule color. There is a 47% chance of a grade 5 capsule (light blue), a 39% chance of a grade 4 capsule (purple), a 13% chance of a grade 3 capsule (red), and a 1% chance of receiving any capsule with grades 0-2 (bronze, silver and gold).

[image]

Source, [Splatoon 3 wikia](https://splatoonwiki.org/wiki/Shell-Out_Machine).